# Python + SQLite: How to make table columns using a list?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to make a sqlite table with a lot of columns.

The table and sqlite codes look like...

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE MyTable
          (AAA  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT,
           BBB  INTEGER,
           Col_1  TEXT,
           Col_2  TEXT,
           Col_3  TEXT,
           Col_4  TEXT,
           ........There are 1000x columns here......
           Col_1000  TEXT);
           ''')
```

Because there are so many columns, I use a list to generate the column names.

```
SQL_Title_List = []
for i in range(1, 1001, 1):
    Temp = "Col_" + str(i)
    SQL_Title_List.append(Temp)
```

My question is, how to write the SQL codes **professionally**? It'll be very painful to write them manually.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your database design if you have a table with 1000 columns.

Comment: Are the column names predefined or you are reading from some file?

Comment: @DanielRoseman :-( actually I have more than 1000 columns.

Comment: @MYGz The columns are new. The data should be imported from a text file.

Comment: @doglas: I have to concur with @DanielRoseman, this means your database design *is* seriously wrong. ESPECIALLY if they are all named `Col_` + some number!

Comment: `SQL_Titles = ['Col_{}'.format(column) for column in range(1, 1001)]`

Comment: Or `SQL_Titles = map('Col_{}'.format, range(1, 1001))`

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks. But how about the column AAA and BBB, that I also want to have.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @doglas this isn't really a chat forum. Ask a singular good question, get a hopefully singularly good answer. See [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Please don't do that. This is a very un-SQL thing to do. Instead you should create another table with three rows - main_row_id (a foreign key to the main table), col_number (the number 1 to 1000), value (the text field).

So instead of 1,000 columns per row, you have 1,000 *records* in the second table per row.

If, on the other hand, you need to store such table because it makes sense, you shouldn't use SQLite but rather something else. I would look at pandas.

Comment: Not really. SELECTing thousands of records while JOINing tables is usually a problem.

Comment: Thanks! Pandas sounds good. I actually thought sqlite could do this task easily.